# Making an image show up on a JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to make a chessboard (8x8 grid) and fill it with background squares, but it always appears as a grid of empty squares. The image is called `emptysquare.jpg` but it does have a background color.

How to I correctly add an image to a `JButton` on the grid I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your chessboard is empty is due to the fact that you call `JFrame#setVisible` *before* adding your `ChessSquare` buttons to your panel. Ensure all component have been added before making this call.

Also set the `Icon` like this in `ChessSquare`

```
ImageIcon empty = ...
setIcon(empty);
```

Comment: I've moved those commands below, but the grid is still just blank squares.

Comment: You need to call `setIcon` in your `ChessSquare` class

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, but what would go in front of setIcon?

Comment: Nothing, youre already _in_ the `JButton` class as youre extending it. See update

Comment: I've updated my code too, the thing is it still comes up blank.

Comment: Solved it, thanks. I thought that it would find the images in a sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setIcon( empty )` in your constructor.

It's allowed-but-awkward to call `setVisible( )` before the squares are added, but if you do you may need to repack to get the layout right.

The call to `setLayout( )` must be moved before the loop.

Comment: I've made these changes but the squares are still blank. Do I need to prefix setIcon with something?